# How to have multiple nested arrays in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the collection data from a csv file with header. When i run my query

```
db.ties.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { "SHOP": "$SHOP" },
           isLinkedTo: { $push: { "PERSON": "$PERSON", "CITY": "$CITY", "ROOM": "$ROOM", "STYLE": "$STYLE", "hasDonated": {"DATE": "$DATE", "OBJECT": "$OBJECT", "COST": "$COST", "COLOR": "$COLOR", "PAYMENT": "$PAYMENT"}}}
         }
     },
     { $out: "ties"}
   ],
   { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

I have like result:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "Shop": "FirstShopNameCovered"
        },
        "isLinkedTo": [{
            "PERSON": "Carleen",
            "CITY": "Rome",
            "ROOM": "Kitchen",
            "STYLEPREFERED": "Modern",
            "hasDonated": {
                "DATE": "2019-10-11",
                "OBJECT": "Set of dishes",
                "COST": 72,
                "COLOR": "White",
                "PAYMENT": "Credit card"
            }
        }, {
            "PERSON": "Carleen",
            "CITY": "Rome",
            "ROOM": "Kitcher",
            "STYLEPREFERED": "Modern",
            "hasDonated": {
                "DATE": "2018-10-26",
                "OBJECT": "Set of chairs",
                "COST": 353,
                "COLOR": "Grey",
                "PAYMENT": "Coupon"
            }
        }, {
            "PERSON": "Pernick",
            "CITY": "Venezia",
            "ROOM": "Bathroom",
            "STYLE": "Minimalist",
            "hasDonated": {
                "DATE": "2018-09-18",
                "OBJECT": "Mirror",
                "COST": 68,
                "COLOR": "Brown",
                "PAYMENT": "Credit card"
            }
        }
```

You can see that there is replicated the Person **"PERSON": "Carleen"** with all data with 2 different arrays **hasDonated**.

I wish have something like this result, with person not replicated that contains all **hasDonated** arrays where he is present:

```
    "_id": {
        "Shop": "NameCovered"
    },
    "isLinkedTo": [{
        "PERSON": "Carleen",
        "CITY": "Rome",
        "ROOM": "Kitchen",
        "STYLE": "Retrò",
        "hasDonated": {
            "DATE": "2019-10-11",
            "OBJECT": "Set of dishes",
            "COST": 72,
            "COLOR": "White",
            "PAYMENT": "Credit card"
        },
        {
            "DATE": "2018-10-26",
            "OBJECT": "Chair",
            "COST": 53,
            "COLOR": "Grey",
            "PAYMENT": "Coupon"
        }
    }, {
        "PERSON": "Pernick",
        "CITY": "Venezia",
        "ROOM": "Bathroom",
        "STYLE": "Minimalist",
        "hasDonated": {
            "DATE": "2018-09-18",
            "OBJECT": "Mirror",
            "COST": 68,
            "COLOR": "Brown",
            "PAYMENT": "Credit card"
        }
```

How can I do to have the result like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to `$unwind` to flat the array. Then group the `hasDonated` using `$group` where unique is found by combination of "_id" and "PERSON" as you mentioned.

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$isLinkedTo"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        per: "$isLinkedTo.PERSON"
      },
      isLinkedTo: {
        $first: {
          PERSON: "$isLinkedTo.PERSON",
          CITY: "$isLinkedTo.CITY",
          ROOM: "$isLinkedTo.ROOM",
          STYLEPREFERED: "$isLinkedTo.STYLEPREFERED"
        }
      },
      hasDonated: {
        $addToSet: "$isLinkedTo.hasDonated"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      "isLinkedTo.hasDonated": "$hasDonated"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      hasDonated: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      isLinkedTo: {
        $push: "$isLinkedTo"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6Ou3CWPD6u)**

Comment: But this is the document you posted and working fine in mongo playground, right?

Comment: can you post your data and share it with me? If the document s not structured, it wont work anywhere. Your data was not formatted. So I formatted, where you can get the idea

Comment: Screenshot of the data structured in the collection?

Comment: No, just post it in mongo playground and share the link

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include education
`{$ out: "collection"}` so that it can be saved in the database. but once inserted and pressed the Enter key to execute the query, I get a `duplicate key error collection: index: _id_ dup key: {_id: {SHOP: \ "SecondShop \"}} "`

Comment: id cannot be duplicated

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zdGc5Adtzy4 this is the link. Why in Mongo Playground works and in Mongo Shell no?

Comment: I now check with my local mondo instance, its working , fine:')

Comment: open your monog shell and type `use myfirsttry;`

Comment: then copy and paste below code `db.test.insert({ "_id": { "SHOP": "SecondShop" }, "isLinkedTo": [ { "PERSON": "Sissy", "CITY": "Rome", "ROOM": "Bedroom", "STYLEDPREFERED": "Normal", "hasDonated": { "DATE": "2019-07-28", "OBJECTS": "Clothes", "COST": 30, "COLOR": "Blue", "PAYMENT": "Coupons" } } ] })`

Comment: Without istruction to save in database `{$out: "collection"}` its works, but with this instruction compare error of duplicated key collection. I share another link with this instruction. https://mongoplayground.net/p/J9zB6BJUwxy. If you also run on mongo playground the same error appears

Comment: Is there another statement to save changes to the database instead of $out?

Comment: I found the problem, gimme some time, i will correct it

Comment: I have updated the code, you can check it now. Just need to put last `$group` as I wrote

Comment: Wew, thank you, I forgot to add group stage. If any problem, feel free to contact me

Comment: FYI all content for a question should be contained in the *question*. Please don't encourage people to post content externally (or within comments under a proposed answer).

Comment: Also, any clarifying comments should be posted under the question itself. If extended conversations are required, then it's best to open a [Chat].